# Matlab to Matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I would like to convert 2 snippets of Matlab code to Python/Matplotlib.

Here is the first snippet.

```
Xs = 1.8;
fs = 10; 
fi = pi/3;

t1 = -0.1;
t2 = 0.2;
t = [t1, t2];

x = inline('Xs * sin(2 * pi * fs * t + fi)','t','Xs','fs','fi');
fplot(x, t, 2e-3, 1,'-', Xs, fs, fi)
xlabel('t'); ylabel('x_s'); grid on
title('x_s(t) = X_s sin(2 \pi f_s t + \phi_s)')
```

The first 6 SLOC I can convert to python because they are basic variable assignment. For SLOC 7 however, I do not know the equivalent to the Matlab inline() function in Matplotlib, assuming there is one. I have searched the Numpy namespace and there is no function with the name 'inline'. I was also greeted with an error message verifying the above statement when running the code. Also, on SLOC 8, the fplot() function and the format of some of its parameters I cannot find an equivalent to in Matplotlib. The fplot() function is also not in the Pylab namespace.

The second snippet is not much different than the first, I will post it just as reinforcement for the above:

```
x = inline('Xe*exp(b*t)','t','Xe','b');

Xe  = 0.8; 
b = -0.5;

t1 = 0;
t2 = 8;
t = [t1, t2];

fplot(x,t,2e-3,1,'-',Xe,b)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('x_e')
title('x_e(t) = X_e e^{b t}')
grid on
```

I have very little experience with both Matlab and Python/Matplotlib, however, I have managed to convert some other Matlab code snippets to Matplotlib. I am working on a portfolio for school which requires I use Matlab for plotting. However, Matlab isn't free so I have opted to use Matplotlib instead.

Thanks in advance whatever help you give.

Answer (score 1):

For "inline" equivalent you can use "lambda" functions.

Comment: Could you give me some more information, maybe an illustration of a lambda function doing what one of the above inline code snippet does?

Comment: @rgb-one, for example `x = lambda t, Xe, b:  Xe*exp(b*t)`, previously defined `from numpy import exp`.